# A different (more intuitive?) definition of the tangent space and the differential. Why are they not used?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition, smooth-manifolds, differential

Probably a silly question, but the following seem to me intuitive definitions to make:

---

Throughout let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds of dimension $m$ and $n$ respectively.

**Definition:** the ***tangent space*** of $M$ at $p\in M$ is $\mathbb{R}^m$, or
$$\{p\}\sqcup \mathbb{R}^m$$
if you will (both spaces are isomorphic, so there is no relevant difference).

*Intuition:* given a chart $(U,\phi)$ at $p$, we see that $U$ is homeomorphic to an open subset $\phi(U)$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$, with $\phi(p)$ the image of $p$ under such homeomorphism. The natural tangent space at $\phi(p)$ is of course $\mathbb{R}^m$. Furthermore, if $T_pM$ is defined by means of derivations it can be shown that the derivations
$$\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\Bigg|_p,\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_m}\Bigg|_p\right\}$$
form a basis of $T_pM$, which therefore is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

**Definition:** let $F:M\to N$ be a map between manifolds, with $p\in M$ and $F(p)=q\in N$. Given the charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ of $p$ and $q$ respectively, we say $F$ is ***differentiable*** at $p$ iff so is
$$\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}:\phi(U)\to\psi(V)$$
at $\phi(p)$; in such case we define the ***differential*** $dF_p$ of $F$ at $p$ as the differential of $\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}$ at $\phi(p)$.

*Intuition:* again by 'interpreting' $p$ and $q$ as $\phi(p)$ and $\psi(q)$ respectively, and in their corresponding neighborhoods.

---

However, authors go through the trouble of defining the differential of $F$ in terms of derivations (or germs, or whatever objects were used to define the tangent spaces). **Why is this the case?**

Comment: Saying $p\sqcup\Bbb R^m$ is wrong. Perhaps $\{p\}\times\Bbb R^m$ if you want to be correctly pedantic?

Answer (score 1):

The tangent space is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ as you say, but not in a natural way.  One way of thinking of this is in terms of continuity.  If there were a continuous way of identifying each tangent plane of, say, the $2$-sphere $S^2$ with $\mathbb R^2$ (with basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$), this would imply the existence of an everywhere nonvanishing tangent vector field on $S^2$, where at every point we would choose the tangent vector corresponding to, say, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.  But we know that the $2$-sphere does not admit such a vector field by the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Comment: Could you give a more precise definition of what _a continuous way of identifying each tangent plane of $S^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$_ is?

Comment: Locally in a neighborhood $U$ say, the tangent bundle of any surface is diffeomorphic to a product $U\times \mathbb R^2$ (again only locally).  Note that continuity is also a local property.  Continuity would just mean that the map from $U\times\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ is continuous, in the usual sense of multivariate calculus.  @Sam

Comment: Sorry, but I'm struggling to fully grasp your answers/comments. I'm still learning about smooth manifolds. Let's go by steps: given a $2$-manifold $M$ and a neighborhood $W$ of $TM$, there is a diffeomorphism $W\to U\times\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Sam, it is better to state this as follows: Given any sufficiently small neighborhood $U$  in a surface $M$, the tangent bundle restricted to this neighborhood will be "trivial" in the sense of being diffeomorphic to $U\times \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Where $U$ is some neighborhood of the surface?